# How to handle dynamic routing logic for consumers in rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, publish-subscribe, amqp, enterprise

I have a use-case where the producers publish some events and the consumers are initially bound to the producers' exchanges. Over time, certain conditions change and the binding or the routing keys (for consumers) needs to be updated, since their subscription interests have changed. Can I handle this dynamic routing scenario in RabbitMQ?

Comment: So what you are asking is: can I remove bindings and create new bindings?

Comment: You didn't say what platform you're using, but in general, yes, this is possible.

Comment: Is there a reason to not consider pub-sub model. This should work for you as consumers can decide dynamically whether to process a message or not, as it arrives, based on current state (which is affected by external events)

Comment: kra3- Well I am intending to use the pub/sub model. The only caveat in my case is that the consumers will get many messages which they will not process, an slightly inefficient model. I was thinking if there is a better way to ask the broker to only send "interested" messages. But that again, will change the topology of the RMQ dynamically, not ideal either. I am trying to get a recommendation of either approach

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fairly straightforward.

RabbitMQ provides the [Queue.Bind](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v1.7.0/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-1.7.0/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#queueBind) and [Queue.Unbind](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v1.7.0/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-1.7.0/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#queueUnbind) methods. When your consumers wish to receive information about a particular topic, they would `Bind` the queue to that topic via a topic exchange. When they are no longer interested in a particular topic, the binding would be removed for that topic using `Unbind`.

Comment: I am using c++ and amqp-cpp library. The problem I have is not so much exactly to bind or unbind to an exchange. But the issue with routing keys in general. Basically my consumers which are bound to an exchange, can have a change in external condition which makes the current message received as "not acceptable". Basically the condition thta renders if the current message is appliable can dynamicaly change based on an external event. One option is to check the validity of the message once it arrives and discard it if its not applicable. But I am trying to see if there is another approach.

Comment: Also another follow-up clarifcation: lets say I have a topic exchange and I need to set up a consumer with an array of routing keys not just one pattern ( for example I am interested in keys = {"A", "B", "C"}
Can I do this with the same exchange?
Assuming my producer will tag the message with the those keys?
Also can I change this on the fly?

Comment: Once a message ends up in a queue, there is no getting it out of the queue without consuming it first. You don't have to process it, but you have to at least take it and have a look. You could purge the whole queue, but you would lose everything in it.Events are static things (they are part of history), so if your consumers are dynamic then that's going to have to be dealt with there.

Comment: You can bind a queue via as many keys as you want to a particular exchange